# Раскрутка сайта-блога

Tags: seo, раскрутка

Доброго времени суток! Имеется следующий простенький [сайт](http://book-fan.ru/) личного творческого характера. Посоветуйте как можно раскрутить его, чтобы он появился в поисковых системах по определенным запросам? Что можно сделать помимо тега meta name="keywords" и создание заголовков (h1, h2, h3) для текстов которые потенциально должны попасть в поиск роботами поисковых систем?

Answer (score 6):

в гугле полно инфы, советую читать

http://www.webeffector.ru/wiki/

http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/

Не любите читать? полюбите.

http://vk.cc/1FtuGI (не открывать!!)

Comment: спасибо за инфу) плюсанул ответ.